# Django - Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server

Tags: python, django

I installed django and virtual env.
I created a project(nandiasgarden-project) and an app(pizza).
Edited pizza.views under pizza

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'pizza/home.html')

def order(request):
    return render(request, 'pizza/order.html')
```

created 2 html files under - pizza/templates/pizza/

home.html

```
<h1>Nandia's Garden</h1>
<a href="{% url 'order' %}">Order a Pizza</a>
```

order.html

```
<h1>Order a Pizza</h1>
```

settings as below:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pizza',
]
```

And finally urls as

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from pizza import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.home name='home'),
    path('order',views.order name='order'),
```

]

when run server and then fire the website, I get below:
Not Found The requested resource was not found on this server
How to fix this and what's the resolution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an invalid syntax while defining a route

Previous:-

```py
path('',views.home name='home'),
path('order',views.order name='order'),
```

Corrected :-

```py
path('',views.home,name='home'),
path('order',views.order,name='order'),
```